# Is reactor-core-micrometer published on Maven central?

Tags: project-reactor, micrometer

I wonder if `reactor-core-micrometer` is publicly available? I could not find it there.

I ask because I noticed that `Schedulers.enableMetrics();` is deprecated but I couldn't find `Micrometer.enableSchedulersMetricsDecorator();` to be publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

Reactor provides a built-in integration with Micrometer. Check [Exposing Reactor metrics](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#metrics) for details.

You could also check e2e demo based on Prometheus & Grafana that exposes both Reactor's schedulers and business metrics [Reactor monitoring demo](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-monitoring-demo).

**Update**

Starting from `v3.5.0` the new module [`reactor-core-micrometer` is introduced](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/3015) for more explicit way of bringing
metrics in reactor-core. The entry point is the `Micrometer` class.

As for now `v3.5.0` is not yet released and not available in maven central but dependencies are published to https://repo.spring.io/milestone (e.g. [reactor-core-micrometer:1.0.0-M3](https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone/io/projectreactor/reactor-core-micrometer/))